# C# MVC3 Boolean editor template or html helper for a Byte model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, checkbox, boolean, html-helper

is there was a way of making a checkbox editor template or html helper for a Byte MVC model property?  Someone else did ask basically the same thing here, [Display a byte as a checkbox using a EditorTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078150/display-a-byte-as-a-checkbox-using-a-editortemplate), whose solution I may end up using; furthermore, it links to somewhat related [Checkbox for nullable boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849774/mvc3-creating-checkbox-for-nullable-boolean).  However, neither of these actually establish a working editor template/helper, so while I would assume that means I'm going to have to settle the matter somewhat unconventionally, I just wanted to double-check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EditorTemplate and a custom model binder for the `byte` type and checking in the binder if the type is boolean to return 1 or 0