# Convert bool? to bool in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i have checkbox in my which is like this `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SKUs.Jewish)` but my Jewish in database is `nullable` type so it gives me an error `cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'`. how do check my model that it has values then it should show that else not.please help.

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SKUs.Jewish.HasValue ? (bool)model.SKUs.Jewish : false)

Comment: ITS GIVING ME AN ERROR :Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849774/mvc3-creating-checkbox-for-nullable-boolean

Answer (score 6):

You could use the following:

```
@Html.CheckBox("SKUs.Jewish", Model.SKUs.Jewish.GetValueOrDefault());
```

If the value is not set it uses the nullable types default value which is false.

Comment: When post with that way sending null values?

Comment: @CanÜrek Hi Can, I improved my answer above. I think that works better.

Answer (score 0):

With a nullable type you check if it has a value with `thing.HasValue`, and get at the actual value using `thing.Value`.

Comment: how do i check in @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SKUs.Jewish) in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

And finally i solve that problem. If you are using a checkbox; uncheck Allow Nulls option of your field in your DB. That's it!

Comment: And what if the field needs to be null sometimes?