# Nullable Object Must Have a Value ASP.NET MVC 5 Checkbox For

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Hi I have a CheckBox For

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.VisitRequested.Value, new {onClick = "showHide();"})
```

It throws the exception (above) if the checkbox isn't clicked. I would like the value to be 0 or false if the check box remains unchecked.

The model code is:

```
[DisplayName("Request a Visit")]
public Nullable<bool> VisitRequested { get; set; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3: Creating checkbox for nullable boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849774/mvc3-creating-checkbox-for-nullable-boolean)

Answer (score 3):

The `Value` property of a `Nullable<T>` throws an `InvalidOperationException` when the value is null (actually when `HasValue == false`). Try:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.VisitRequested, new {onClick = "showHide();"})
```

Just use `model.VisitRequested` and eventually wrap it inside an `if`:

```
@if (Model.VisitRequested.HasValue)
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.VisitRequested, new {onClick = "showHide();"}) 
}
```

Comment: System.Nullable <bool> does not contain definition for GetValueOfDefault

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: I've used GetValueOrDefault(false)

Comment: Can you show the complete line of code you have in your view?

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.VisitRequested.GetValueOrDefault(false), new { onClick = "showHide();" })

Comment: That looks fine. Seems like your exception has nothing to do with this line of code.

Comment: Does this exception occurs at the same line of code? You might want to  ask a new question if it's not.

Comment: Yes its at the exact same line

Comment: Ah I understand. What if you just use `model => model.VisitRequested`, without the `GetValueOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's because `model.HasValue` is false. Add;

```
 if (model.VisitRequested.HasValue)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.VisitRequested.Value, new {onClick = "showHide();"});
 else
    //somethings wrong, not sure what you want to do
```

Basically that is indicating that the object is null. In the docs you'll find;

Exception:
InvalidOperationException
Condition:
The HasValue property is false

which is what you're encountering.

Comment: model does not exist in the current context. Do I have to use @{} symbols for the code?

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 I don't think so, I would guess there's some other little syntax error that's causing it. Oh, yeah I just saw it. I'll edit. I was accessing `HasValue` from `model` when there is one more layer of indirection. The error message isn't intuitive :|