# CheckboxFor is always null

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, checkboxfor

i have a class ViewModel below:

```
public class UserViewModel{
  public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model CoreHRM.WebUI.Models.UserViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive.Value)
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
}
```

Controller

```
var isActive = userModel.IsActive;
```

but it's always get null value if i checked my checkbox.

help me to solve this problem?

Comment: check your model is setting value for the IsActive property or not

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849774/mvc3-creating-checkbox-for-nullable-boolean

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive.Value)
```

Try

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
```

I'm not sure you supply the value like that for a CheckBoxFor - you supply the model property

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsPublic.Value,
    new { @Id = "IsPublic",@Name="IsPublic" })
```