# how to generate check box using @HTML.CheckboxFor with bool?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

In a form, I want to add a CheckBox to bind model value back to action. My model column is of type `bool?`

I tried the following code but getting error `"Cannot implecitly convert type bool? to bool"`

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.AccomPublic)
```

Please help me with correct way of using @HTML.CheckBoxFor.

Comment: Doesn't that help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849774/mvc3-creating-checkbox-for-nullable-boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CheckBoxFor` use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.AccomPublic)
```

This will render a drop down with 3 values (True, False and Not Set)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen but cant do UI change.

Comment: You cant use a checkbox for a nullable `bool`. A checkbox has 2 states (true and false) where as a nullable `bool` has 3 states (true, false and null) so you need to change the property to bool, or change the UI to use a dropdown (or 3 radio buttons), or create you own control

Comment: If I do something like "<input type="checkbox"  name="AccomPublic" checked="@Model.AccomPublic" id="publichospitalasaprivatepatient" />" will it work with model binding ? Actually I tried and it is not working. Clicking or unclicking check-box do not change value in model. Is it expected behavior ?

Comment: No it wont work, because unchecked checkboxes do not post back so the only possible values you can recieve is `true` (checked) or `null` (not checked so nothing posts back). You can never check for `false`

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of your property is of type nullable i.e. bool?
Set your property as public bool nameofproperty{get;set;} And use @Html.checkboxFor(m=>m.nameofproperty)