# Checkboxfor Always return null in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkboxfor

I am using CheckBoxFor for submitting boolean value.

**Demo.cshtml**

```
<div class="checkbox">
     <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i.ReportModel.Is_XRay.Value) X-Ray</label>
</div>
```

[image]

Even I've selected checkbox, I am getting false in hidden value.

> Also When I submit page, I am getting checkbox value null

Comment: Is there any reason `Is_XRay` is nullable? I think that's probably the cause of your problem...

Comment: No its just null in database. But there always be the value True/false

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849774/mvc3-creating-checkbox-for-nullable-boolean. I think that might help. In this case it might be best to look at the answer from Darin (which is to create a view model with a non-nullable property).

Comment: Ok. You were right. It was problem with the nullable<bool>. I replaced it will bool and now it's working. Strange but true :D

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: Not strange at all - the `CheckBoxFor()` method is for binding to a `bool` not a `Nullable<bool>` - if you did want to bind to a nullable `bool`, then you use `EditorFor(i => i.ReportModel.Is_XRay)` which generates a dropdownlist with 3 values - `True`, `False` and `Not Set` (for `null`)

Answer (score 0):

That hidden input should always have a value of false. This is because when your checkbox isn't checked, no data would get sent to the server. To workaround this, there is a hidden input with the value false that is always posted to the server. You'll notice the URL should have your variable name twice (once with true, once with false) when submitting with the box checked. Now to address your real issue - I suspect it may have something to do with the name of your variable. Razor will insert underscores when you are using objects in a list, and I think you're having one already is giving the model binder a hard time.