# CheckBoxFor - Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to incorporate a checkbox in my view.
Here is what I have in my View:

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Chart)
```

Note, I get the following: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return type in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

I have the following in my model:

```
    public bool ? Chart { get; set; }
```

Note how Chart is a nullable boolean.

I also tried to do the following:

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Chart.Value)
```

But I get: Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849774/checkbox-for-nullable-boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `CheckBoxFor()` to bind to a `bool?` (nullable). The method accepts a `bool` as the expression.

A checkbox has 2 states (on/of or `true/false`) and a `bool?` has 3 states (`true/false/null`).

Note that the signature of the method is

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
```

To bind to a `bool?`, use `@Html.EditorFor()` which will generate a dropdownlist containing 3 values.

Alternatively if you want a checkbox, then use a view model and make you property `bool`.