# Check/Uncheck all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've seen many check/uncheck all checkboxes scripts. But far most does not respect that if I toggled all checkboxes using the "checked all"-checkbox and then uncheck a single one in the list, the "checked all" checkbox is still checked.

Is there an elegant way of handling this case?

Comment: From a UI point of view you probably want a [three state checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html) so you can show the some-on-some-off case as something else. But you have to fake these in HTML, or <5 at least. I've used a good implementation before but it's not one of the answers in that question - can't remember where though. [The first example there](http://shamsmi.blogspot.com/2008/12/tri-state-checkbox-using-javascript.html) can do this out of the box, although not in jQuery, and using separate images for each state rather than one + CSS.

Comment: Another alternative example: http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/mSFts/

Comment: @Raynos: Nice, but it doesn't check "check all" when manually checking all checkboxes.

Comment: Never thought of three state checkbox. Intersting. :-)

Comment: @ThiefMaster that wasn't requested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('#checkAll').click(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});

$('input:checkbox:not(#checkAll)').click(function() {
    if(!this.checked) {
        $('#checkAll').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else {
        var numChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked:not(#checkAll)').length;
        var numTotal = $('input:checkbox:not(#checkAll)').length;
        if(numTotal == numChecked) {
            $('#checkAll').attr('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/HuM4Q/

As pointed out in the question's comment, a regular checkbox is not perfect for this. My implementation disables the "check all" box as soon as *one* checkbox is unchecked. So, to uncheck all still-checked checkboxes you'll have to click twice (first to re-check the unchecked ones and then to uncheck all other ones).
However, with a tri-state checkbox this might still be necessary as the state order might be unchecked->indefinite->checked->unchecked, so you'd need two clicks to come from indefinite to unchecked.

---

Since you probably don't want to check ALL checkboxes on your page with "Check All", replace `input:checkbox` with e.g. `.autoCheckBox` or `input.autoCheckBox:checkbox` and give those checkboxes `class="autoCheckBox"`.

If you want all checkboxes inside a certain form, simple use `#idOfYourForm input:checkbox` or `form[name=nameOfYourForm] input:checkbox`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by attaching a click handler to each of the target checkboxes, and have that handler un-check the "control" checkbox based on the collective state of those target checkboxes. So, something like this:

```
// Control checks/unchecks targets
$('#controlcheckbox').click( function(){
  $('.targetcheckboxes').attr('checked', this.checked );
});

// Targets affect control
$('.targetcheckboxes').click( function(){
  if( $('.targetcheckboxes:not(:checked)').length ){
    $('#controlcheckbox').attr('checked',false);
  }
});
```

Even better -- you could attach this logic to an enclosing container element, and watch for the event using `.delegate()`:

```
$('#some_container').delegate('.targetcheckboxes','click',function(){...} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selectall").click(function(){
    var checked = $("#selectall").attr("checked");
    $(".selectone").attr("checked",checked);
});
```

For setting select all

```
 $(".selectone").click(function(){
   var net = $(".selectone").map(function(){ return jQuery(this).attr("checked");}).get();
   var flg = true;
   if(jQuery.inArray(false, net)){
     flg= false;
   }
   $("#selectall").attr("checked",flg);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$('tbody input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if ($(this).closest('tbody').find('input:checkbox').not(':checked').length) {
        $('#checkAll')[0].checked = false;
    }
});
```

This assumes that `#checkAll` is in the `thead` section of your table.