# How can I get my CheckBoxList to have three possible states?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get my `CheckBoxList` to have three possible states ? More precisely, is there a way to have three possible states for each checkbox : checked, unchecked, undefined (in most GUIs this is represented as a full square).

Alternatively, do you recommend another control that would meet these needs ?

**UPDATE** : Ok, given that HTML does not support tri-state checkboxes, I'm looking for a way to 'CSS' (color fill, highlight, etc...) the checkboxes of the items that are in that 'undefined' state from my server point of view.

Comment: how about a dropdown?

Comment: Not easily as the checkbox is rooted in HTML heritage. Check this for alternative solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html or this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20159/ASP-NET-TriState-CheckBox-Made-Easy

Comment: How about if you use Javascript? http://shamsmi.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/tri-state-checkbox-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use CheckBoxList anyway, since I need two states accessible by the user, and a third one not accessible by the user but to display inconsistencies.

The way I have solved this is through Javascript + CSS. Some bits of ideas here: http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

Answer (score 5):

Not all GUIs represent undefined as a full square. That's why it's going to be clearer to use one of the following:
1. [Radio boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k30eyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
2. [Dropdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
3. [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4d7ktzs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Any asp.net control you use will ultimately need to be rendered as an html checkbox, which can only be checked or unchecked. You could use a data- attribute to keep track of extra state behind the scenes, but that wouldn't be reflected in the UI.

I suppose you could also implement a client-side solution using JavaScript and CSS as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could just extend or derive from the CheckBoxList and create your own custom control from it.

Here is an example of this.

[Custom CheckBoxList](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/129037/Custom-CheckBoxList-with-SelectedValues-Property)