# Do we still have to set checkboxes to indeterminate using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html) was asked back in 2009 and the most recent answers are from 2011, which suggest that you need to use Javascript to set a checkbox to an indeterminate state.

Is this still the case, or is there HTML5 markup now supported by browsers for this scenario?

I ask because this has to be a common requirement, and it seems odd to have it only accessible via Javascript.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4724216/100342) confirms that there is still no way to express this through markup.

Comment: Ok, but the content of that answer hasn't really been changed since 2012 (which is when the update was added). Hence this question.