# Getting Check_Box to have a default value of nil with Bootstrap Switch

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html

I'm using the Indeterminate switch (which keeps the checkbox between true and false). The issue is that the switch defaults to true.

Basically I want that field to submit as nil unless user specifically selects true or false.

Answer (score 0):

**Jackson** Is this all you need?
Same use for Toggles.

```html
<label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked> Checked
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
      <input type="checkbox" unchecked> unChecked
</label>
```

Comment: Hi @AngularJR - I want my checkboxes to start with a null value until they are specifically checked or unchecked by the user.

Comment: Hi there, Sorry I thought you just wanted to default it to false.There was another answer here just before which was to try `data-indeterminate="true"` but I don't think that is going to fly for what you want here. Try searching to see if the answer is out there.

Comment: Have a look at this [**link here**](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/)  And also [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html)

Comment: I ended up just using a dropdown with a prompt