# CSS to convert an checkbox to look like an Intermediate checkbox without using JavaScript

Tags: html, css, checkbox

How can I convert a normal Checkbox to look like an intermediate checkbox using CSS without JavaScript?

[image: Normal Checkbox]

[image: Expected Look of Checkbox]

For the following DOM elements, what would be the CSS in class **intermediate-checkbox** to make it look like an intermediate checkbox?

[image: Intermediate Checkbox]

```
<div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="intermediate-checkbox>

                 Intermediate Checkbox
            </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: A quick Google result https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question as well.  As far as I know it isn't possible to set an indeterminate state on a checkbox without javascript.

Comment: @Martin which part of it? Does it use javascript? It is css only solution so I don't get your comment

Comment: @Morpheus have you even run that codepen for yourself? it has two stages, empty and ticked it does **not** have three stages which is what the OP is asking for. `Empty` -- `Intermediate` --  `Checked`

Comment: @Martin ah, missed that part :) images got my attention initially

Comment: To be fair, it wasn't expressed by the OP (`TheKojuEffect`: ***edit your question to clarify***) but by the term "intermediate" I assume they want a 3 stage tickbox. @Morpheus

Comment: If that is the case, I don't think it is possible in css only. `any <input type="checkbox"> element whose indeterminate DOM property is set to true by JavaScript.` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate

Comment: [A similar (high ranking) question and answer which states it needs a Javascript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html)

Comment: @Martin I just want the checkbox to look like an intermediate checkbox. I'll update the question. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Morpheus I take back my criticism; it seems the OP does still only want a *two* step checkbox, but they didn't clarify this in the question.

Comment: a 3 steps check could be faked in CSS given 3 dfferent style to the label and hidding the input. pointer-events would help and :before to insert the checkmark : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xrpwpJ  anyhow, the label will be there to be styled. Intermediate state might be avalaible in a quantum state:) but it confused everyone here

Answer (score 2):

you can use below css to get the same

```css
input[type="checkbox"].hidden {
  display: none;
}

.demoCheck {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked.hidden+label {
  background: tomato;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked.hidden+label:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 12px auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="demo">
<label for="demo" class="demoCheck demoCheckLabel"></label>
```

Comment: This only has two views: empty and intermediate. No tick.

Comment: Same i posted .

Comment: @LokeshGupta This does not answer the OP's questions, it only changes the display but does not change the actual value.

Comment: @LokeshGupta Is it possible to do it without using image?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect easy use an SVG data blob in the CSS

Comment: Image use is easiest way to get it but if you need it without image, u can use background color or use before and after to get it

Comment: a single :before is enough to show the checkmark, background or shadow can be used when unchecked. pointer-events can even fake an intermediate state at screen (3 steps : unchecked, unchecked but restyled,   checked) .  CSS can do weird things sometimes ;)  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/xrpwpJ/