# Checkbox with square

Tags: c#, webforms

On a website I want to display a list of entries with a header entry in a table. When checking the checkbox in the header it should check all the checkboxes, and unselecting it should unselect them all.
The problem is when I unselect some entries in the list, the checkbox in the header should display a third state, usually this would be a square in the middle instead of a checkmark as seen [image: here].
How can I do such a thing with asp:checkbox?

Edit I found my answer here: [Tri-state Check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html)

Comment: A checkbox typically has 3 states. `Selected`, `Unselected`, `Undefined`. Usually the `Undefined` state make it look like a square select like in your picture. I have not worked with `ASP` in years so i can't give you a definitive answer but this is the rough idea. It might help you find out how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tri-state Check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html)